# Degrees of separation between famous mathematicians

Tags: soft-question

I was recently doing some reading on Wikipedia, and I noticed that if you go far enough though Isaac Newton's notable students' students' students. . . (and so on), eventually one was Augustus De Morgan's adviser, and one who was J.J. Thomson's adviser.  There seems to be a great linkage between all of these famous scientists (and it begs the question: can good advisers create more good students, or do good students successfully get good advisors?).  Are there any particularly interesting links between famous mathematicians or other scientists?

Comment: Well, both. One the one hand, a good student is more likely to seek F. Amos Guy as adviser than to seek Uthar Lee Nondescript, and a promising student has better chances to be accepted by Mr Guy than a nondescript or bad student. On the other hand, a good teacher and adviser can tickle out more from her/his students than a mediocre one.

Comment: Not exactly relevant, but not irrelevant either: [the Erdős–Bacon number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Bacon_number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably already know this, but just in case:

[Mathematics Genealogy Project](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/)

Comment: Actually, I'm quite amazed that I've never heard of that site. Thanks!

Comment: You'll all be happy to know that I have a direct line (through my calc II teacher last semester) of knowledge coming directly from Euler, Gauss, Laplace, Bernoulli, Hilbert, and Fourier.  Truly remarkable when you think about it.

Comment: @user160931: Cool!  I can "only" claim (through my thesis advisor) Hegel, Schelling, Fichte, Kant, Mersenne, Leibniz, Melanchthon and van Ceulen... :)

Comment: Wow, I got Gauss, Poisson, Dirichlet, Fourier, Laplace and Lagrange. And I do engineering, not maths. MGP is an awesome site.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [Mathematics genealogy project](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/) and get lost following all fascinating links and finding famous mathematicians.
The tree on the front page is already stunning.